# Issuer URI of Spring Security OAuth2 Authorization Server

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm developing OAuth 2.0 authorization server and resource server using `Spring Security OAuth 2.0 2.3.4.REELEASE`. Little did I know that Spring has deprecated it in favor of `Spring Security`. However, authorization server is not included in the migration to `Spring Security`. Only the resource server is included as they are encouraging users to use products instead (one is [KeyCloak](https://www.keycloak.org/)).

But like many others, I really have to develop my own authorization server so I keep on using `Spring Security OAuth 2.0` but only for the authorization server. As for resource server, I'll be using the resource server from `Spring Security`. I think authorization and resource servers are independent and they are based on the standards of `OAuth 2.0` so the implementation could be from different frameworks.

My problem is specifying the authorization server via [issuer-uri](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2resourceserver). I could not determine how Spring OAuth 2.0 authorization server exposes its `issuer-uri` if there is any. I could not find either any docs how to create one if it does not have one be default.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Spring Security Oauth has ended support you should use the Spring Authorization Server now (https://spring.io/projects/spring-authorization-server). For the isser uri there you can use the base uri of the server. To verify this you can check the well-known-Endpoint under /.well-known/openid-configuration.
The isser uri in the authorization server can be edited with the ProviderSettings:

```
    @Bean
    public ProviderSettings providerSettings() {
        return ProviderSettings.builder()
            .issuer("https://authorization-server:8443")
            .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution you are looking for lies within the TokenEnhancer. So, implement a custom token enhancer and add the iss key like so.

```
   public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();
    additionalInfo.put("iss", "issuer uri here");
    ...
    ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
    return accessToken;
```

}